# Custom collection/enumeration - how to filter returned collection?

Tags: vb.net, class, collections, enumeration

Currently I have the following code...

```
For Each Ord as clsOrder in Orders
   If NOT Ord.Status = voided then
     'do stuff to all orders that are not voided...
   endif
Next
```

What I am wondering is if there is a way to get the returned/enumerated collection to not even return items which are voided so I would not need the nested if statement to avoid those? Some sort of custom enumerator or something?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the collection with a [`Where` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx), like

```
For Each Ord as clsOrder in Orders.Where(Function(o) Ord.Status != voided)
    ...
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) Where clause like this (available in .NET 3.5 and above):

```
Public Class clsOrder
    Public Property Status As Integer
End Class
```

.

```
Dim Orders As New List(Of clsOrder)

'populate Orders here

For Each Ord As clsOrder In Orders.Where(Function(x) x.Status <> voided)

Next
```

Note that this is no quicker than doing it the way you posted but it is a little easier to read

Comment: What references does this require? I dont seem to have a .Where on my collection objects..

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?

Comment: What type is `Orders`? this should work on a List(of T) or an Array

Comment: Public Class clsOrders
        Inherits Collection(Of clsOrder)

Comment: Dim orders as new clsOrders()

Comment: Looks like you have declared an array of a collection. You are probably better to use a generic `List(Of T)` see my example code